# Perpetual motion

Tags: perpetual-motion

Does this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PDeK6rprA4) have a physics behind or it is fake? Where the energy comes from? 
It looks like a perpetual motion!

Comment: Aren't a few minutes of observation a pretty small fraction of eternity to make such an extrapolation to perpetual motion?

Comment: LOL, I could have determined it was a Czech accent after 3 seconds of the audio. And I was right. ...  There are many ways how to create this video. For example, there may be some alternating magnetic field beneath the table. The YouTube user has posted lots of optical illusions and other tricks so this is just another trick, I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be fraud (as suggested on [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14283/can-permanent-magnets-be-exploited-to-create-energy/14295#14295)), but rather a good joke. The YouTube video ultimately links to [this disclaimer](http://free-energi.com/index.php?a=dis) for a great little website.

Apologies if I ruined the joke.

Comment: I love the disclaimer on the site: *This website presents a serious risk of damaging your self-confidence in case you decide to take any content of this website seriously and try unsuccessfully to utilize it any useful way.*

Comment: @Gugg, sorry i couldn't quite catch that, was it true or joke?

Comment: @Richard The video and the website are jokes. But good jokes. (And one can only guess how he does it.) I especially like the things he does with (the button on) his [power extension cord](http://free-energi.com/index.php?a=1).